# magento 2 Session size of 26991656 exceeded allowed session max size of 756000

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, magento2.4.4

I was unable to log in for admin after upgrading Magento 2.3.1 to Magento 2.4.4.
So i tried to set value of system/security/max_session_size_admin to 256000. Which was working fine for me for some time. But after some time I was getting Session size exceeded in system.log. So again tried to increase the value. But each time it is working fine for some time and later on getting Session size exceeded the issue in system.log. I tried to set the value of system/security/max_session_size_admin to 0 but if I am doing so then I am unable to log in.

Even though I tried this solution but it is also not working for me:
https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028606711-Login-redirect-when-trying-to-login-to-Magento-Admin

I have referred to many blogs but nothing is working for me any help on this is grateful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Can you please check this out and confirm if it works for you

```
bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 0
bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_storefront 0
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my issue description I have already tried this solution but If I set the value of system/security/max_session_size_admin to 0. If I am doing so I cannot log in to the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set our `"Max Session Size in Admin"` to `768000` in

> Stores->Configuration->Advanced->System -> Security tab